# How to create a login script based on the root password in Linux Distro Openwrt?

Tags: bash, shell, cgi, openwrt

I have a web application in Linux Distro Openwrt ,  where I am using the root password for login by user.  I was able to change the root password from a 'password change' html page using a cgi program in c by calling the system command to change the root password.

`system("(echo 'newpassword'; sleep 1; echo 'newpassword') | passwd root");`

Now the problem I am facing is that , I am not getting how to make the login page functional.. ( how to login with the root password? what sort of cgi should I use there? or should I call a script which may be already there in openwrt?) . I found a script login.sh in /bin folder, but Is that a login script (script given below)?

```
#!/bin/sh
if ( ! grep -qs '^root:[!x]\?:' /etc/shadow || \

 ! grep -qs '^root:[!x]\?:' /etc/passwd ) && \
[ -z "$FAILSAFE" ]

then

    echo "Login failed."
    exit 0


else

cat << EOF



=== IMPORTANT ============================
  Use 'passwd' to set your login password
  this will disable telnet and enable SSH
 ------------------------------------------

EOF
fi
exec /bin/ash --login
```

How is LuCI doing that?..

I hope the question is clear.

Thanks.

Comment: probably you should used PAM (plugable authentication modules)
it checks OS user credentials that can use used for any services or applications

Answer (score 0):

Best is Go via PAM

```
/usr/share/doc/python-pam/examples/pamtest.py
```

Hit this on your shell and you can get idea

Or if you are looking for CGI Script can use this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28812/is-it-possible-to-test-user-name-and-password)

Or bash script here  [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21705/how-to-check-password-with-linux)

This was discused in unix & linux of stackEchange

Here is Python Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import PAM
from getpass import getpass

def pam_conv(auth, query_list, userData):

    resp = []

    for i in range(len(query_list)):
        query, type = query_list[i]
        if type == PAM.PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_ON:
            val = raw_input(query)
            resp.append((val, 0))
        elif type == PAM.PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF:
            val = getpass(query)
            resp.append((val, 0))
        elif type == PAM.PAM_PROMPT_ERROR_MSG or type == PAM.PAM_PROMPT_TEXT_INFO:
            print query
            resp.append(('', 0))
        else:
            return None

    return resp

service = 'passwd'

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    user = sys.argv[1]
else:
    user = None

auth = PAM.pam()
auth.start(service)
if user != None:
    auth.set_item(PAM.PAM_USER, user)
auth.set_item(PAM.PAM_CONV, pam_conv)
try:
    auth.authenticate()
    auth.acct_mgmt()
except PAM.error, resp:
    print 'Go away! (%s)' % resp
except:
    print 'Internal error'
else:
    print 'Good to go!'
```